# WinForms control allowing me to select multiple dates in a year?

Tags: .net, winforms, calendar, controls

I am looking for a WinForms control that allows me to select multiple dates in a year.

Does anybody know if there is one already available or would I have to develop one myself?

Basically I would like to see all months with their days and be able to select/de-select by clicking on the different days.

Comment: There is a [workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1739247/395718) with standard MonthCalendar. There are also calendar controls available on the Net, both free and licensed. Have you tried searching for .NET calendar control?

Comment: @Dialecticus Yes, I did try searching for .NET calendar control. Without success for a yearly view.

Comment: Good job on downvoting without a comment. Congrats.